# Where are missing pages 3 and 4 for patent 101,875?

Tags: specification

The patent 101,875 is missing pages 3 and 4.  Is there any way to obtain the missing pages?

Comment: All pages look fine in the PDF from https://www.google.com/patents/US101875

Answer (score 1):

You are right!  They are missing from my version too.

You should contact the "office of publications" at the USPTO at www.uspto.gov.  If the pages are missing from the electronic files, they were probably are missing from original official gazette paper publication.  In that case, you would have to order a copy of the "file wrapper".  This is a collection of all of the papers filed by the applicant as well as the examiner's response(s).  That would have the full original disclosure.

Just curious, how did you come upon this?